# iPhone doesn’t support any of app’s architectures. You can add arm64e architecture to app's Architectures build setting

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9

I’m on Xcode 9. I just got my iPhone XS Max. I tried to install my app onto it.

I kept getting

> iPhone doesn’t support any of app’s architectures. You can add iPhone’s arm64e architecture to app’s Architectures build setting.

[image]

**Build Settings**

[image]

How can I prevent this error?

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's not because of iOS 12 - note the error message. This is the ARM64e architecture, which is used on the A12 and later. ARM64e compiles into ARMv8.3 instructions, which enable Pointer Authentication Codes. This means that rather than traditional flow control instructions (BL, RET) the code is expected to use the authenticating variants (BLA[A/B], RET[A/B]), and likewise for some pointer loading instructions (LDR => LDA[A/B], etc).

The ARMv8.3 instructions greatly improve security, as most hacks are achieved by overwriting pointers and subverting the program's flow control. Apple didn't announce this as a feature of the ARM12, but it is nonetheless, and going forward will be the standard on all Apple processors - and likely sometime in Android devices as well.

More about this at http://newosxbook.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=19557

Answer (score 4):

The iPhone XS Max came with iOS 12 and you need Xcode 10 to build for iOS 12.

Comment: I see the same error when using XCode 10 beta. Should I expected to work after set the Target to `ios 12` ?

Comment: Use the released version, not the beta.

Comment: It is not even release yet.

Comment: Is it realease yet ? I just log in to Apple Developer site, I only see `Xcode_10.1_Beta` please let me know if that is the one, you referring to ?

Comment: You can download it from App Store directly, `10.0` is released, `10.1` has its first beta out.

Comment: Let me try that. Thanks.