# Xcode arm64 Vs arm64e

Tags: ios, xcode, arm64, xcode10.1

Xcode 10.1 mention Support for arm64e (Preview). Anyone have any idea about arm64e. Any difference between arm64 and arm64e.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_1_beta_2_release_notes?language=objc

I searched arm64e, but couldn't find any proper explanation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52481335/iphone-doesn-t-support-any-of-app-s-architectures-you-can-add-arm64e-architectu

Answer (score 142, accepted):

The arm64e architecture is used on the A12 chipset, which is added in the latest 2018 iPhone models (XS/XS Max/XR). The code compiles to ARMv8.3, which brings support for new features. Namely:

- Pointer authentication
- Nested virtualization
- Advanced SIMD complex number support
- Improved Javascript data type conversion support
- A change to the memory consistency model
- ID mechanism support for larger system-visible caches

> The A12 features an Apple-designed 64-bit ARMv8.3-A six-core CPU

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_A12

Read more about the architecture here as well:

https://community.arm.com/processors/b/blog/posts/armv8-a-architecture-2016-additions

Answer (score 17):

### `arm64` vs `arm64e`

Both are [ABIs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) (lower level APIs) which compile to instructions (defined by an ISA/ instruction set architecture). arm64e is used on Mac M1's and iPhones. The differences between them are the points in [Giovanni's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52624441/7365866).

### `arm64e` vs `ARMv8.3`?

Both are ambiguously called "architectures". `arm64e` is not an ISA but an ABI (Application binary interface), and ARMv8.3 is an ARM ISA (technically an extension to AArch64).

In summary, `arm64e` is an ABI (often called architecture, but **not** ISA), which compiles to a real ISA. The new Apple devices use arm64e, including M1 macs.

### iPhones (e.g. A14, A15), M1 Macs, M1 Pro Macs, etc.

They  all use the arm64e ABI, but Apple has an ISA license, and create custom ISAs.

### ABI vs Architecture?

The Android documentation has a useful guide about [Android ABIs](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis), containing general information:

> Different Android devices use different CPUs, which in turn support
> different instruction sets. Each combination of CPU and instruction
> set has its own Application Binary Interface (ABI). An ABI includes
> the following information:
> [read more there](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis)

Answer (score 10):

To test arm64e with an app, update the `Architectures` setting in `Build Settings`. More details at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/preparing_your_app_to_work_with_pointer_authentication.

Note that if you have CocoaPods dependencies, all of the Pods build targets must be similarly changed.

If any of the CocoaPods dependencies are binary instead of source pods, make a request to the vendor like https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/4110