# Building for ARM64e on Apple silicon

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, apple-m1, apple-silicon

I'm building my command line app, and noticed that all the binaries I create are of type `arm64`.

However, all the bins that ship with macOS 11.4 are `arm64e`.

i.e. running `file` on my app built on an M1 MacBook shows:

`Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64`

Whereas, running file on the system `xxd` app on the same machine shows:

`Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64e`

I've looked in Xcode and cannot see how to augment this, should Xcode not be building `arm64e`? If so how can I achieve the same?

Here's a picture:
[image]

**EDIT: I think the answer might be, the arm64e ABI is unstable and not in use for anyone but Apple?**

Comment: Discussion and references here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52624308/xcode-arm64-vs-arm64e

Comment: Interesting, so is the arm64e ABI just not available yet for general use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main difference between targeting arm64 and arm64e is [ARMv8.3's Pointer Authentication Codes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/preparing_your_app_to_work_with_pointer_authentication). Since the specific ABI hasn't stabilized, Apple is only using it for their own platform code since they can easily recompile the entire OS version with a different ABI by shipping a new OS whereas they can't really force all developers to start using a new ABI.

Despite this, you can compile for arm64e simply by choosing "other..." on the architectures drop down and typing in `arm64e`. By default, macOS will refuse to run any non-Apple code that has the arm64e slice (since they want to prevent anyone from shipping arm64e code before the ABI is stable). You can, however, override this behavior and allow macOS to run non-Apple arm64e code by setting the `arm64e_preview_abi` bootarg:

```
sudo nvram boot-args=-arm64e_preview_abi
```

Note that you will need to disable system integrity protection to do so. This bootarg is meant to allow developers to prepare their software to run with pointer authentication enabled and really not much else.